# AddChild Function Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am encountering a problem with this addChild function I created (This function is located in the Document Class):

```
public function enemySpawn(locX:Number,locY:Number)
{
    stage.addChild(this.basicEnemy);
    this.basicEnemy.x = locX;
    this.basicEnemy.y = locY;
}
```

Basically, whenever I call this function from the constructor of my Document Class, it only replaces the previous child with next one down the line. Is there anything I could do to fix this problem?

Here's the Document Class just in case if you guys need it:

```
package com.basicSurvivalEngine.documentClass
{
    import com.basicSurvivalEngine.assetHolders.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;

    public class Document extends MovieClip
    {
        public var mcMain:Player;
        public var basicEnemy:BasicEnemy;
        public var survivalLevel:MovieClip;
        public var wallCollisionArray:Array = new Array();

        public function Document()
        {
            mcMain = new Player(this);
            basicEnemy = new BasicEnemy(this);
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
            // constructor code
        }
        public function init(event:Event)
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,levelHandler);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,levelTransition);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,vCamMovement);
            this.enemySpawn(-2800, 650);
            this.enemySpawn(-2700, 650);
            this.enemySpawn(-2600, 650);
            this.enemySpawn(-2500, 650);
            addChild(mcMain);
            mcMain.x = 225;
            mcMain.y = 100;
        }
        public function update(event:Event)
        {

        }
        public function levelHandler(event:Event)
        {
            this.survivalLevel = this["survivalLevel"];
            for (var i:int = numChildren - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var child:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);
                if (child.name == "wallCollision")
                {
                    this.wallCollisionArray.push(child);
                }
            }
        }
        public function levelTransition(event:Event):void
        {

        }
        public function vCamMovement(event:Event):void
        {
            this.mcMain.x -= (x-(((mcMain.x+(mcMain.width/2))-(stage.stageWidth/2))*-1))/15;
            this.mcMain.y -= (y-(((mcMain.y+(mcMain.height/2))-(stage.stageHeight/2))*-1))/15;
            this.survivalLevel.x -= (x-(((mcMain.x+(mcMain.width/2))-(stage.stageWidth/2))*-1))/15;
            this.survivalLevel.y -= (y-(((mcMain.y+(mcMain.height/2))-(stage.stageHeight/2))*-1))/15;
            this.basicEnemy.x -= (x-(((mcMain.x+(mcMain.width/2))-(stage.stageWidth/2))*-1))/15;
            this.basicEnemy.y -= (y-(((mcMain.y+(mcMain.height/2))-(stage.stageHeight/2))*-1))/15;
        }
        public function enemySpawn(locX:Number,locY:Number)
        {
            stage.addChild(this.basicEnemy);
            this.basicEnemy.x = locX;
            this.basicEnemy.y = locY;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I can observe you are just adding to the stage the same object (basicEnemy) every time you call enemySpawn. Thats your problem, if you want a new enemy to be spawned it should be a new obj

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    protected var enemies:Array = new Array();
    public function enemySpawn(locX:Number,locY:Number)
    {
        var basicEnemy = new BasicEnemy(this);
        stage.addChild(basicEnemy);
        basicEnemy.x = locX;
        basicEnemy.y = locY;
        enemies.push(basicEnemy);
    }

    public function vCamMovement(event:Event):void        
    {
            this.mcMain.x -= (x-(((mcMain.x+(mcMain.width/2))-(stage.stageWidth/2))*-1))/15;
            this.mcMain.y -= (y-(((mcMain.y+(mcMain.height/2))-(stage.stageHeight/2))*-1))/15;           
            this.survivalLevel.x -= (x-(((mcMain.x+(mcMain.width/2))-(stage.stageWidth/2))*-1))/15;                  this.survivalLevel.y -= (y-(((mcMain.y+(mcMain.height/2))-(stage.stageHeight/2))*-1))/15;            
            foreach(var enemy in eneimes) {
                enemy.x -= (x-(((mcMain.x+(mcMain.width/2))-(stage.stageWidth/2))*-1))/15;
                enemy.y -= (y-(((mcMain.y+(mcMain.height/2))-(stage.stageHeight/2))*-1))/15;
            }        
        }
```

delete the `public var basicEnemy:BasicEnemy;` and create a new enemy

Comment: What do you mean by creating a new enemy?

Comment: A new instance of BasicEnemy. You are adding the same object to the stage, which is already on the stage. So you need to use new instances of Basic Enemy

Comment: ...And what code would I need to replace `public var basicEnemy:BasicEnemy;` with?

Comment: I'm now getting null object references after deleting `public var basicEnemy:BasicEnemy;`...